# React - Testing method that gets passed down to child component

Tags: reactjs, istanbul, enzyme

I have a component that renders a child component, and in the process it passes down a method as a prop. It's working as intended, but due to work reasons I have to have a majority of the code covered. As of now I'm not sure how to go about testing this method. Here is the parent component method I am passing down:

```
_onSelectCategory (categoryNo) {
    this.setState({
        selectedCategoryNo: categoryNo,
        selectedCategoryData: null,
        equipmentPageNo: 1
    });

    if (categoryNo) {
        this._getCategoryData(categoryNo);
    }
}
```

Here is where I am passing it down:

```
<CategoryTree
  parentCategoryNo={ parseInt(localStorage.getItem("equipmentCategoryNo")) }
  sdkPath={ localStorage.getItem("sitename").toLowerCase() + "/categories" }
  onCategorySelect={ this._onSelectCategory }
/>
```

I am testing using Enzyme, Chai, Mocha, Sinon, and Istanbul. How can I go about testing this using enzyme and getting it covered by istanbul? When using `mount` the child component renders Loading as it doesn't enough data to fully render inside the test.

EDIT: I believe I know how to get the CategoryTree to render properly in order to simulate a click event that calls the method I am trying to test, but I need to use setState on CategoryTree which is being stubbed in the current render of its parent component (the one that holds _onSelectCategory).

Comment: (Unrelated, but pull out the calculations in the `CategoryTree` properties to make it easier to think about.)

Comment: What are you trying to test? `_onSelectCategory`? That it's being passed to `CategoryTree`? That it's being called on an `onCategorySelect`?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, im trying to test that it gets called if I use the onClick in the CategoryTree component. The issue is the CategoryTree has a state that has to be set in order to get it to actually render, so if I use `.debug()` on the parent component (i.e. the one im testing) it won't render the element that has the onClick for calling `_onCategorySelect`

Comment: If you're testing the on click then that test belongs in the category tree tests, and the container component should just test that it's sending the right method.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do I do that by using enzymes `.find` and find the CategoryTree and make sure that _onSelectCategory is being passed as a prop?